# Explain the LINQ to XML for a beginner below?

Tags: linq-to-xml

Can someone explain the LINQ to XML below?  Also, what is the correct way to check if the method returned a List with Data?  Do you just check if the List is empty.

#### Code:

```
public List<Listing> GetList()
{
    if (File.Exists(this.xmlFilePath))
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(this.xmlFilePath);

        var listings = from row in doc.Root.Elements("listing")
                       select new Listing
                       {
                           A = (string)row.Element("A"),
                           B = (string)row.Element("B"),
                           C = (string)row.Element("C"),
                           D = (string)row.Element("D"),
                           E = (string)row.Element("E")
                       };

        return listings.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return new List<Listing>();
    }
}
```

#### XML:

```
<Listings>
   <listing>
     <a>A</a>
     <b>B</b>
     <c>C</c>
     <d>D</d>
     <e>E</e>
    </listing>
    <listing>
     <a>F</a>
     <b>G</b>
     <c>C</c>
     <d>H</d>
     <e>I</e>
    </listing>
</Listings>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML this applies to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `listings` has any data by examining the result of the `Count()` method on the `listings` variable, and to answer the question asked in the comments section below, "So, there is no way to actually return `null`? I have to return a `List<listing>()` object?", please see the following code:

```
public List<Listing> GetList()
{
  if (File.Exists(this.xmlFilePath))
  {
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(this.xmlFilePath);

    var listings = from row in doc.Root.Elements("listing")
             select new Listing
             {
               A = (string)row.Element("A"),
               B = (string)row.Element("B"),
               C = (string)row.Element("C"),
               D = (string)row.Element("D"),
               E = (string)row.Element("E")
             };

    // Check if we have any matches         
    if(listings.Count() > 0)
    {
      return listings.ToList();
    }

    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
```

I think that's what you're after.

There isn't much to explain about how the code works. In the first part of the query:

```
var listings = from row in doc.Root.Elements("listing")
```

The expression `doc.Root.Elements("listing")` selects all of the `<listing>` elements below the document root (`<Listings>`).

The second part of the query creates a new `Listing` object for each `<listing>` element and assigns the inner text of each of the `A,B,C,D` and `E` child elements to each of the `A,B,C,D` and `E` properties of each new `Listing` object created.

The line containing: `return listings.ToList();` returns a generic `List<T>` of `Listing` objects.

Using the sample XML provided, you'll find that each `Listing` object's `A,B,C,D,` and `E` properties will be `null`. This is because the character case of each of the `row.Element()` selectors is different from the XML being queried, i.e. your XML has `<a>` and `row.Element("A")` uses an uppercase `'A'`. XML node matching in LINQ to XML is case-sensitive.

Comment: So, there is no way to actually return null? I have to return a List<listing>() object?

Comment: What about the explanation of the LINQ to XML part?

Comment: Can you post the XML this applies to?